# php function Not Displaying form

Tags: php, session, authentication

Im having a problem displaying a php function. Its for an admin log in form.

The Function Look Like this -

```
 function displayAdmin(){

//test if login is valid


if (isset($_SESSION['adminLogin'])){
if($_SESSION ['adminLogin']=="valid"){

    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">location.replace('addproduct.php')</script>

<?php
}

 else { 
 // test if login is invalid 
 // display error message and login form 
 if($_SESSION['adminLogin']=="invalid") { 
 echo "<div>Incorrect User ID and/or password provided</div>"; 

 ?>
<form name="adminLogin" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                <div id="sign_up_form">
                    <label><strong>Username:</strong> <input type = "text" name="userID" class="sprited"/></label>
                    <label><strong>Password:</strong> <input type="password" name="passWord" class="sprited"/></label>
                    <div id="actions">
                    <a class="close form_button sprited" id="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                    <a type ="submit" name="adminSignin"class="form_button sprited" id="log_in" href="">Sign in</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
 <?php
 } 
}

?>

<form name="adminLogin" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                <div id="sign_up_form">
                    <label><strong>Username:</strong> <input type = "text" name="userID" class="sprited"/></label>
                    <label><strong>Password:</strong> <input type="password" name="passWord" class="sprited"/></label>
                    <div id="actions">
                    <a class="close form_button sprited" id="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                    <a type ="submit" name="adminSignin"class="form_button sprited" id="log_in" href="">Sign in</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>

 <?php
 } 

} // end of function
```

And on my page where I am wanting the function to sit the code looks like this -

```
<?php
 session_start();

 // Test that page title has been created
 if (!isset($pageTitle)) {
 $pageTitle = '<< Page title not set >>';
 }

 // include the myFunctions file
 include('includes/myFunctions.php');

 // test if login details have been keyed in
 if(!empty($_POST["userID"])) {
 // Store userID and passWord in local variables
 $userID=$_POST["userID"];
 $passWord=$_POST["passWord"];

 // check database for valid customer
 checkValidAdmin($userID, $passWord);
 }
 ?>
```

and then -

```
<div id="sign_up">
                <h3 id="see_id">Administration Log in</h3>
            <span>Please sign in using the form below</span>
                <div><?php  displayAdmin(); ?></div>
                <a id="close_x" class="close sprited" href="#">close</a>
            </div>
```

I have searched long and hard for this problem but can not seem to find the issue, if the issue jumps out at anyone I would love to hear from you!

Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely your `$_SESSION ['adminLogin']=="valid"` condition is not true. Check it is set properly or `session_start();` is called at beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['adminLogin']` value is empty i.e. not set or null. that is the reason function inside condition not satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, have tried the echo in there too and still no go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you did'nt return the html string.

You should assign the form to a variable, and at the end of the function , return this variable.